# How can I revert xlwings automatic conversion from date format to number format?

Tags: excel, datetime, xlwings

I have a Dataframe with Date column that I want to transfer to Excel using Xlwings, maintaining the Date format. Xlwings automatically converts dates to numbers. To avoid this the dates were converted to strings using both astype(str) and dt.strftime(). Nevertheless, numbers persist despite dates yielding dtype('O').
?
Test code.

```
import xlwings as xw
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

msft = yf.Ticker('msft')
datos_msft = msft.history()
datos_msft.reset_index(inplace=True)
wb = xw.Book()
hoja = wb.sheets[0]
datos_msft['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datos_msft['Date']).dt.date.astype(str)
 hoja.range('A1').value = datos_msft
```

Please teach me how to transfer the workbook to Excel preserving the Date format.

Comment: I don't have the issue. Regardless of including the line ***datos_msft['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datos_msft['Date']).dt.date.astype(str)*** or not, my Excel shows the Date values as `Date 27/06/2023, 28/06/2023, 29/06/2023, 30/06/2023...` with format `d/mm/yyyy` .